# Is it ok to have FSM update AnimatorController and viceversa?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to figure what would the best practice be to keep these two in sync or find out if this is a bad practice altogether. Actions on my states alter the AnimatorController's parameters needed to trigger the desired animation while on that state. This works pretty well for the most simple cases, but then I have animations that after finished they transition automatically to let's say Idle state on the AnimatorController and then I have the need to let my FSM know that I'm on the Idle state now, which feels as breaking the pattern.